# Finding the spaces in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, function, space

Is there an alternative function for finding the position of the first space in a non-string entry in excel? =FIND(" ", value) seems to only work for string variables.

Tried =FIND(" ", value) to locate the position of a space between a date and time in a DATETIME stamp.

Comment: Date/time are stored as doubles.  So for just the date: `=INT(A1)` and the time: `=MOD(A1,1)`

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `=FIND(" ", TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"))` This converts to text in date time format.

Comment: And, if you just want the numerical value of part of the date: the day `=DAY(A1)`, or the month: `=MONTH(A1)`, or the year: `=YEAR(A1)`